# How to deploy approval process using ANT/Eclipse in salesforce

Tags: deployment, approval-process, migration-tool, ant

I am trying to deploy approval process to cutomer Production orgs. It is difficult to do the manual creation of approval in each customer org. Anybody know this can be done by ANT/Eclipse ? Thanks in advance

Comment: use changeset boss:).Why take trouble with eclipse or ANT

Comment: Mohith we want from organisation to organisation not as sandbox to production.  From source org to any other salesforce org I should be able to migrate approval process.

Comment: i see now .but we have metadata for sure so it should be like normal migration in eclipse .Just extract in eclipse using updated version (v 28) and deploy .Same like normal deployments i believe

Comment: Do you know how to extract the metadata xml using ANT tool or exlipse?

Comment: Hi Shebin, If you have gotten an answer to this question then please mark an existing answer as the correct one or add a new answer yourself. Thanks

Answer (score 14):

You will be able to pull/push the approval process using a the following package.xml. The ApprovalProcess element will pull down the Approval Process and the Workflow element will pull down any of the actions that are referenced in the Approval Process for that action. Replace CustomObject__c with whatever object(s) your approval processes are on, this will make sure actions such as field updates are also pulled down when doing a refresh.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>ApprovalProcess</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>CustomObject__c</members>
        <name>Workflow</name>
    </types>
    <version>28.0</version>
</Package>
```

The ability to access approval processes directly without using change sets has only been possible since the Winter '14 release.